# Azure Logic Apps Http-Call Output (Outputs in general ?) Changed?

Tags: json, azure, http, azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

I logged in today to make another logic app today, and i noticed the return output for (in this example) a Http-call has changed.

Before, i have a memory of the whole object showing in the output of an action in the workflow. Now i just se this:

Picture below:
[image]

The output body is only a string in some kind of encryption...

Does the Workflow definition Language where i want to reach one specific value in the Json-body still work? Or was this Update a major overhall.

I'm lost here.

Comment: Notice that the content is of type "application/xml" hence it is base64 encoded. Perhaps the service you are calling from your logic app has started returning xml instead of json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the Workflow definition Language where i want to reach one specific value in the Json-body still work?

Yes, We can still do it, seems like you at the designer over view of a run, if you want to see full of inputs and output click on the Run details tab on top of this screen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7COJG.jpg)

The content is base64 encoded, if you want to decode with in the logic apps for any other action input, we can use the base64 function which are explained here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#functions)